# Include Rails STI parent with children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance, sti

I have two types using a STI Model - Single Table Inheritance

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cycle 

class Cycle < Entry
  has_many :entries
```

In the cycle/show.html.erb I have a typical table that displays all the entries belonging to this cycle.

```
<% @cycle.entries.each do |entry| %>
<table>display rows of data from entries</table>
<% end %>
```

Is there a clean way I can include the *parent* Cycle data in the first row of the table without repeating the markup with @cycle.value

Comment: Not sure I understand the question... you want to include attributes from the parent cycle in the table?  Why not just refer to them?  `@cycle.name` or `@cycle.updated_at` ...

Comment: I'd like to get the parent Cycle data (which naturally contains nearly identical fields to its child entries). I'll eventually be displaying this data as a chart, so if I can get it all in one *each* loop, it will make things easier later.

Comment: Surely this would cause issues, like an infinite loop or something?

Comment: @RichPeck - I'm not trying to do anything recursive, just include the parent data in the loop without repeating code/markup. This is starting to feel like something to handle as a scope?

Comment: Hmm okay :) Just wondered, as your Cycle inherited from Entry, yet still `has_many :entries` too - seemed recursive to me!

Comment: I'd still like to find a Controller based way to bring the Parent record into the loop (it will always be the first entry), as I'll be reusing similar code throughout the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so put the "displays rows of data" into a partial called, say '_table_lines' where you refer to the model as "object"

(e.g.

```
<ul>
<li><%= object.description %></li> 
<li><$= object.created_at %></li>
</ul>
```

)

Then

```
<%= render partial: 'table_lines', locals: {object: @cycle} %>
<% @cycle.entries.each do |entry| %>
<%= render partial: 'table_lines', locals: {object: entry} %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, that information IS available, just prefix with `@cycle` instead of `entry`...

```
<li><%= entry.description %></li> 
<li><$= @cycle.description %></ul>
```

... the @cycle attributes are available in each `each` loop.  This is assuming you are looping on `@cycle.entries` as your example shows.

Comment: I see how that would work, though that feels repetitive. I'll eventually need to loop through this data to build a json array which will include the parent first.

Comment: By definition it IS repetitive... you want to include `@cycle` information on every entry line from an entry collection that's associated from a single `@cycle`.  Did you mean you want (for example) the first line of the table to be parent cycle information and the remainder of the lines to be entry information?

Comment: "the first line of the table to be parent cycle information and the remainder of the lines to be entry information? "
Yes, that's what I need to do. I'll edit the original question.